# Python "Send2Pd" doesn't reach Pure Data's "Netreceive"

Tags: python, send, os.system, puredata

I need to send messages from Python to Pure Data, so I followed [this](https://guitarextended.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/make-python-and-pure-data-communicate-on-the-raspberry-pi/) article.
It was working fine until one day suddenly it stopped working.
Pure Data doesn't receive anything anymore and I have tried this on Mac and Linux environment

I have uploaded script plus patch [here](https://github.com/Nhouse111/Python_to_Puredata?fbclid=IwAR0tr5iECsqooO6SM_MbCw2O4937SyVlvk6zoCBgnkkMfOXobFQnRl_UwVA):
but a equivalent code is:

```
import os
os.system("echo '1;' | pdsend 3000")
```

and Puredata should receive the message with a simple
[netreceive 3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohn5s.png)

Looks like Python and Pure Data can't find a path to communicate.
after i tried so change `pdsend` with it's absoulute path as follow:

```
import os
os.system("echo '1;' | /Users/path_to_pure_data/PureData.app/Contents/Resources/bin/pdsend 3000")
```

it works.

at this point i don't know why Python doesn't automatically find it's path, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

How would Python know that it should look for executables in `/Users/path_to_pure_data/PureData.app/Contents/Resources/bin/`?

For security (and perfomance) reasons, the system will only search for executables in a few select locations, that are defined in the `PATH` environment variable.

You could either add `/Users/path_to_pure_data/PureData.app/Contents/Resources/bin/` to your PATH, or put `pdsend` into a path that is already searched for.

However, this seems to be an overkill in any case, as calling an external application is rather costly, and using `os.system` is probably one of the worst options.

Python is a powerful programming language, and it is very easy to build the client code in Python itself.
Eg this code does not have *any* external dependencies, performs faster, and is safer (and I'd say. it's easier to read as well):

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", 3000))
s.sendall(b'1;')
s.close()
```