# How to send a connect message from Python to Pure Data?

Tags: python, networking, puredata, libpd

I have a mic patch on Pure Data and I want to connect it to a loudspeaker patch. So, it has the command `connect localhost 3000`, where localhost indicates where the loudspeaker patch is and 3000 is the port number that I will use for connection. Is it possible to send this message using a python script, so I don't have to click on the patch?
I'm using libpd for this.

Comment: that's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67209375 (unfortunately i cannot mark this question as a duplicate, as the OP of the older one has decided to not upvote/accept the only answer)

Comment: alternatively i didn't fully understand your question. how are "python" and "puredata" connected? as you mention libpd: is your python application a libpd host?

Comment: are you sure you are *using* libpd? that snippet you posted looks like a profound misunderstanding of how to use it. with libpd, you load a full instance of Pd within your (python) application - this requires more than just `import pylibpd`. once you have Pd running *within* your application, you can send messages to it. you **cannot** use libpd to make python talk to a **separate** Pd instance (e.g. that was started separately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libpd comes with [some documentation](https://github.com/libpd/libpd/wiki/Python-API) and a [few examples](https://github.com/libpd/libpd/tree/master/samples/python) that explain how to use the API.
If the Python API docs are not detailed enough, check the [documentation for some other language binding](https://github.com/libpd/libpd/wiki/libpd#sending-messages-to-pd) - the bindings for the different languages are typically very similar.

Basically, you can simply send a trigger to a receiver within Pd, using `libpd_bang`.

Python:

```py
libpd_bang("connect-to-speaker")
```

Pd:

```
[receive connect-to-speaker]
|
[connect localhost 3000(
|
```

you can of course send some payload using `libpd_float()` or `libpd_list()` or `libpd_message()`.

alternatively, you could also have Pd trigger the `[connect(` message automatically, using `[loadbang]`.